# using css empty to hide an element

Tags: css

Using chrome to inspect I see some code like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>We .... </p>
</div>
<footer class="entry-footer">
                    </footer>
```

Sometimes this footer is empty, and at other's it isn't.

When it is empty I try to hide it with:

```
footer.entry-footer:empty {
display:none;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

So I am either doing something wrong (or I guess it isn't really empty!)

Comment: `:empty` will not work if your element has blank spaces. Does it have?

Comment: Ok. That's probably it.

Comment: Checked again in ff yes 1 space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:empty` requires the element to be empty of whitespace too.

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/dMqedr), `.test.blue` and `.test.red` have white space and don't `display: none;` (without the JS below, where `.test.red` becomes hidden)...

if you want to remove the white space post load, here is some JS to do that:

```
var empties = document.querySelectorAll( '[selector_here]' );
for ( key in empties ) {
    if ( typeof empties[key].innerHTML != "undefined" ) empties[key].innerHTML = empties[key].innerHTML.trim()
}
```

The JS above trims the the whitespace from any element matching the given selector, in my example I used the class `empty` (you can see it working on `.test.red`)

But i would recommend removing it from the HTML

Comment: that's really, really helpful! Thanks

Comment: i moved the php around a bit - now space gone and it all works.

Comment: @maxelcat if you're using php, that too has a trim function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick [test](http://codepen.io/kraigwalker/pen/qZMYxQ) for you and it would seem that white space counts as content. Beginning  your closing tag on a new line will quietly insert a newline character, so which is why your selector for :empty fails.

As a solution, your html should be look like the following:

```
<footer class="entry-footer"></footer>
```

Because there's literally nothing between the start and end tags, the element passes as being `:empty`